# Elliptic curve over prime field with high order roots of unity

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, prime-field

Suppose I have an elliptic curve defined over a prime field $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ where $p$ is a large prime (e.g. 256-bit). Suppose also that $p = kn +1$, where $n$ is a relatively large power of $2$ (e.g. $2^{32}$). This structure implies that $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ has $n^{\mathit{th}}$ roots of unity.

My question is: does the fact that $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ has "high order" roots of unity make curves defined over this field inherently less secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: does the fact that $\operatorname{GF}(p)$ has "high order" roots of unity make curves defined over this field inherently less secure?

Not particularly; the factorization of $p-1$ is not specifically relevant to the strength of a curve over $\operatorname{GF}(p)$.

Now, it is quite relevant to the strength of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$; however that's because the order of the group is always $p-1$ (assuming $p$ is prime), and the factorization of the group order is quite relevant.  However, the elliptic curve (in general) doesn't have order $p-1$; instead, it is $p + \delta$ for some $|\delta| < 2\sqrt{p}$ (the exact value of $\delta$ depends on the precise curve you pick), and it is the factorization of $p + \delta$ which is important.

Comment: Thank you! Quick follow-up: are there any well-known or well-studied curves defined over such prime fields? All curves I've seen so far seem to be defined over prime fields with very small roots of unity.

Comment: @irakliy: there's the NIST curve P-224, which has $p = 2^{224} - 2^{96} + 1$; that certainly has high roots of unity for large powers of 2.  BTW: why is that important to you?

Comment: I've been looking into [STARKs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf). When implementing them over a prime field, the field must have large roots of unity (otherwise computations become prohibitively expensive). The underlying reason is that STARKs require a lot of polynomial interpolations and multi-point evaluations which can be done efficiently using FFT over a domain consisting of roots of unity.